# Discord bot not show "success message" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// fs
const fs = require('fs');
// path
const path = require('path');
// config
const config = require('./config.json');
// config.json
const token = config.token;
// config config.json
const PREFIX = config.prefix;

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: \[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES\] })

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

// message
client.on('message', message =\> {
// message not sent by bot
if (!message.author.bot) {
// if the message starts with the prefix
if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
// split the message into an array
const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/);
// command is the first element of the array
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
// ping command
if (command === 'ping') {
// send a message to the channel
message.channel.send('pong');
}

// success message after login
client.on('ready', () =\> {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
})
// token config file
client.login(config.token);
```

so I run node index.js it's supposed to shown Logged in as "my bot name here" on the VSC terminal and should be online on the discord, but it doesn't and I can't figure it out, mind anyone help

Comment: There are also a lot of backslashes in your code messing up the arrow functions. I'm not really sure how you got to this stage. Is there something wrong with your editor?

Comment: Which version of discord.js do you have?

Answer (score -1):

Formatting will save your life, Bro:
Also, I'd recommend less comments. It's a lot of noise. I refactored this stuff out. Look how much nicer your code looks:

```js
const { token, prefix: PREFIX } = require('./config.json');
const { Collection, Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] })

client.commands = new Collection();

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return
  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return 

  const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }
})

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
})

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Thanks fam, I'll make sure next time to use comment when needed.

Comment: LOL are you going to accept the answer?

Comment: Somehow the code working after I delete some stuff so I assume something was wrong at the beginning, and I don't really know much about javascript.